# Regex ungreedy from the left side (i.e., narrowest match possible from both sides)

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

Let's say I'm trying to match `/dog.*lab/` against this text:

*"I have a dog. My dog is a black lab. He was created in a laboratory."*

Greedily, it would match "*dog. My dog is a black lab. He was created in a lab*".

I want to find the matches that are narrowest from both sides. If I use the ungreedy modifier like
`/dog.*?lab/` or `/dog.*lab/U` it will match less but still too much:
*"dog. My dog is a black lab"*

Is there a way to make my search ungreedy from the left also, thus matching only "*dog is a black lab*"?

Much thanks. Sorry for the contrived example.

Comment: What if the input is `"dog123lab dog12lab dog1lab"`? Do you want to skip all others and only get `dog1lab` since it's the smallest match possible?

Comment: @polygenelubricants No, I would want those to be three separate matches. I think I would have been more accurate in asking for the _narrowest_ match, not the _smallest_. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a [look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that excludes the occurrence of `dog` between `dog` and `lab`:

```
/dog(?:(?!dog).)*?lab/
```

Comment: This takes a bit more preprocessing logic to prepare my keyword(s) for regex search, but it works perfectly. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
$str = "I have a dog. My dog is a black lab. He was created in a laboratory.";
if(preg_match('/.*(dog.*?lab)/',$str,$m)) {
    var_dump($m);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down-voted. This idea is sound. To force the non-greedy match to be as small as possible, put a greedy search immediately in front of it and then inspect the capture group.

Comment: @Andrew, @codaddict: the downvote didn't come from me, but refer to latest comment from OP about wanting multiple matches. This will only find the last match.

Comment: The last match isn't always the smallest match.  It is for *this* test string, but it's not difficult to come up with a string in which the smallest match is actually in the middle or at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

An idea might be to try to use a negated character set, like `[^.!?]`, which would match all characters except `.`, `?` and `!`, and therefore you can be sure that it is within the same sentence:

```
$string = "I have a dog. My dog is a black lab. He was created in a laboratory.";
preg_match('/dog[^.!?]*?lab/', $string, $match);
echo $match[0]; // Echoes "dog is a black lab"
```

Comment: Thanks. This is true, but I cannot guarantee in my application that the requisite match will be within one sentence or line.